# Python BeautifulSoupHTML table scraping

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to learn how to scrape a page using BeautifulSoup and write it to a csv file. When I start appending columns to the key in a dictionary all the values are appended to each key not just a single one.

I get the information I want:

```
[<td class="column-2">655</td>]
[<td class="column-2">660</td>]
[<td class="column-2">54</td>]
[<td class="column-2">241</td>]
```

Afterwards when I try to assign each value to a key I get:

```
{'date': ['14th November 2016'], 'total complaints': ['655', '660', '54', '241'], 'complaints': ['655', '660', '54', '241'], 'departures': ['655', '660', '54', '241'], 'arrivals': ['655', '660', '54', '241']}
```

Full code (csv writer is just for testing now):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import csv

operational_data_url = "http://heathrowoperationaldata.com/daily-operational-data/"
operational_data_page = requests.get(operational_data_url).text
print(operational_data_page)

soup = BS(operational_data_page, "html.parser")

data_div = soup.find_all("ul", class_="sub-menu")

list_items = data_div[0].find_all("li")

data_links = []
for menu in data_div:
    list_items = menu.find_all("li")
    for links in list_items:
        data_link = links.find("a")
        data_links.append(data_link.get("href"))

for page in data_links[:1]:
    data_page = requests.get(page).text

soup = BS(data_page, "html.parser")
date = soup.find("title")
table = soup.find("tbody")

data = {
    "date" : [],
    "arrivals" : [],
    "departures" : [],
    "complaints" : [],
    "total complaints" : [],    
}

for day in date:
    data["date"].append(day)

rows = table.find_all("tr", class_=["row-3", "row-4", "row-36", "row-37"])
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all("td", class_="column-2")
    data["arrivals"].append( cols[0].get_text() )
    data["departures"].append( cols[0].get_text() )
    data["complaints"].append( cols[0].get_text() )
    data["total complaints"].append( cols[0].get_text() )

#test
with open('test.csv', 'w') as test_file:

    fields = ['date', 'arrivals', 'departures', 'complaints', 'total complaints']

    writer = csv.DictWriter(test_file, fields)
    writer.writeheader()

    row = {'date': day, 'arrivals': 655, 'departures': 660, 'complaints': 54, 'total complaints': 241 }
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In the `for row in rows:` loop you are explicitly appending the value to the list associated with each key.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already and it appends the last number to all

Comment: Try replacing your for loop with the code in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I start appending columns to the key in a dictionary all the values are appended to each key not just a single one.

Currently, your `for row in rows:` loop does this explicitly.

It appears to me that you want to be doing something like this instead:

```
rows = table.find_all("tr", class_=["row-3", "row-4", "row-36", "row-37"])
cols = [row.find_all("td", class_="column-2")[0] for row in rows]
data["arrivals"].append(cols[0].get_text())
data["departures"].append(cols[1].get_text())
data["complaints"].append(cols[2].get_text())
data["total complaints"].append(cols[3].get_text())
```

This will give you the following result for `data`:

```
{'date': [u'14th November 2016'], 'complaints': [u'54'], 'total complaints': [u'241'], 'departures': [u'660'], 'arrivals': [u'655']}
```

Note that this will only work if your `rows` are in the right order.

Comment: Thanks @elethan for the explanation! They were in order, it functions perfectly!